# replace field number by its row position in table sql, mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the table posts, where id_post is primary key & autoincrement

```
id_post  | post
  1        hi1
  3        hi3
  27       hi27
  45       hi45
  67       hi67
  69       hi69
```

I want to update `id_post` in order it to get its row position in the table

```
id_post  | post
  1        hi1
  2        hi3
  3       hi27
  4       hi45
  5       hi67
  6       hi69
```

How could it be done?

I was thinking using `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: You want to update the actual value?  Or convert the value to a new field so you get the order of the fields themselves?  If just add new column you can use Row_Number()

Comment: just update, replace it.

Comment: If you want to update the actual value my first question is why?  Currently in the  table you cant because it is auto increment and the PK.  There are ways to do it but you have to drop the auto increment and PK (and not have any references to that PK in other tables), make the update, using something like Rown_Number(), then add back in the PK and auto increment.  But again why woudl you want to do this?  If you reference this ID anywhere at all it will break all your references

Comment: I need to reorder the posts id from 1 to 1000. without gaps. Do you have any idea of how to make it? I will alter the autoincrement later `ALTER TABLE posts AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000`

Comment: the posts are referenced by its token, so no problem to change the id_post

Comment: I think @Deivdas answer should work for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run these commands:

```
SET @x = 0;
ALTER TABLE `posts` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
UPDATE `posts` SET `id_post` = @x:= @x + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use set oprion as bellow :

```
before 
+--------+--------+
|id_post | itemID | 
+--------+--------+
|  1     |    hi1 |
|  3     |   hi3  |
|  27    |   hi27 |
|  45    |   hi45 |
|  67    |   hi67 |
|  69    |   hi69 |
+--------+--------+

after
--------------------

mysql> SET @nbr=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> update posts set id=@nbr:=@nbr+1 

+--------+--------+
|id_post | post   | 
+--------+--------+
|  1     |    hi1 |
|  2     |   hi3  |
|  3     |   hi27 |
|  4     |   hi45 |
|  5     |   hi67 |
|  6     |   hi69 |
+--------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```